# Attach Event to Bootstrap DatetimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Using Javascript, how can I attach an event listener for when the datetime has been changed in the Bootstrap DatetimePicker ([Homepage](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/))

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        document.getElementById('dtp1').addEventListener('change',function(e){
            //Do Something
        });
    });
</script>
```

However the above function isn't getting fired when I change the date either by using keyboard or the mouse (point and click).

The HTML Looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='dtp1'>
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Date</span>
        <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If someone would advise the correct way to do this, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: I am aware of that. Doesn't help.

Comment: @mickmackusa it can't say what exactly that linked to years ago any more, but https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ redirects to https://getdatepicker.com/4/ now, so I am guessing https://getdatepicker.com/4/Events/ should hold the relevant information now(?).

Answer (score 4):

I worked out a solution that achieves a result.

```
<script>
    $("#dtp1").on("dp.change",function (e) {
        //Do Something
    });
</script>
```